# RegEx for Capturing Number Patterns not Followed by Other Characters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm using C# and want to capture `IP:PORT` with Regex but how to make it not match if after `PORT` the character is `:` ?

test it [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%5c.%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%5c.%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%5c.%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%29%5b%3a%5cs%5d%2b%28%5cd%7b2%2c5%7d%29%28%3f!%3a%29&i=1.22.234.255%3a8181%3au%3ap%0d%0a+++1.22.234.255+80%0d%0a++1.22.234.255++++8080%0d%0a+dddd1.22.234.255%09%0980808%0d%0a1.22.234.255%3a8080aaaaaaa%0d%0a1.22.234.255+8888bbbbbbb&r=%5c1%3a%5c2)

Pattern:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[:\s]+(\d{2,5})(?!:)
```

Expexted result

```
1.22.234.255:8181:u:p // true, it should be false
   1.22.234.255:80 // true
  1.22.234.255    8080 // true
 dddd1.22.234.255       80808 // true
```

Comment: are you trying to match ip addresses ?

Comment: yes, but that not the problem it doesn't need to be valid IP

Comment: Take a look out at [`IPAddress.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8), instead of a Regex

Comment: Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11412956/7177029)

Comment: I'm not validating IP but capturing `IP:PORT` from random string

Comment: This part `[:\s]+` matches this `::: : : : ::: : :::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::`

Comment: @sln the string is proxy list and copied from the webpage, 99.99% there will be no such string :D

Comment: @cieunteung -  It's not good form to say in 99.99%, like lead free ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your port expression `(\d{2,5})` is not grabbing all of the digits. In the unexpectedly-passing expression, if you look at the match groups, they are `1.22.234.255` and `818` (*not* `8181`). The expression does reject `1.22.234.255:8181` because it is followed by a `:`, but the then considers a 3-digit port and accepts `1.22.234.255:818` because the next character is a `1` and not a `:`.

One way to compensate for this is by changing your pattern to reject both colons and digits:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[:\s]+(\d{2,5})(?![0-9:])
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works for all cases

`(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s*(?::\s*)?(?<!\d)(\d{2,5})(?!\d|\s*:)`

https://regex101.com/r/5faUcx/1

Readable version

```
 (                             # (1 start), IP
      \d{1,3} \.
      \d{1,3} \.
      \d{1,3} \.
      \d{1,3} 
 )                             # (1 end)

 \s* 
 (?: : \s* )?
 (?<! \d )

 ( \d{2,5} )                   # (2), Port
 (?! \d | \s* : )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using two different regular expressions, it will be simpler

Expression 1 for spaces:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\d{2,5})
```

Expression 2 no spaces, you must make sure it has an EOL character or /m modifier if you have multiple lines:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\:(\d{2,5})$
```

Match against any of the two and merge the results.

Comment: thanks, it random string I cannot use `^$` because the value could be in the middle and separator should be colon or space `[:\s]`